# Error Console in Spigot server

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

Pops up that error on the console:

Please help me guys i need this for now!

```
Error:

[13:36:23] [Server thread/ERROR]: Ambiguous plugin name `'KwadratowyHardcore' for files `plugins\KHH.jar' and `plugins\KH.jar' in `plugins'
[13:36:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Set PluginClassLoader as parallel capable
[13:36:23] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\KHH.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `me.skyter.hardcore.HardcorePlguin'
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:66) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:131) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:329) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:292) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:198) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:525) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.skyter.hardcore.HardcorePlguin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:64) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
```

Server it spigot 1.8.9!
I compiles with bukkit api 1.7.2, 1.8.8 and spigot 1.8.9 and craftbukit 1.8.9

Comment: The error message looks fairly self-explanatory to me. I'd also recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and following its advice if you want helpful answers. Telling people "i need this for now!" is only likely to annoy people and make it much less likely that they'll want to spend their valuable time helping you out. The fact that this is something to do with Minecraft would imply that the urgency is not quite what you're suggesting.

Comment: You have an invalid plugin. remove your hardcore plugin `plugins\KHH.jar`. problem solved. Don't post non programming questions here. If this is your own plugin, please post relevant source code or the relevant meta-inf content or whatever bukkit uses to decide what main class is.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is invalid. Always look for the line with `Caused by:` (Ctrl+F). You should let the developer of the plugin know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.skyter.hardcore.HardcorePlguin
```

Tells you, that the class with this path could not be found, therefor the plugin is invalid / not able to run.

Make sure the paths match, and check your plugin.yml for the wrong path

Answer (score 0):

You have your main class setted worng in plugin.yml

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `KHH.jar` or `KH.jar` (the older one), maybe having the same plugin twice causes a problem.

```
Ambiguous plugin name `'KwadratowyHardcore' for files `plugins\KHH.jar' and `plugins\KH.jar' in `plugins'
```

If that doesn't solve the error, look at the other posts here, then the `plugin.yml` is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here:

1. In your **plugin.yml**, the "**main**" value doesn't point to the actual
   class that extends "**JavaPlugin**".
2. There are two files containing the plugin with the same name, so
   **Spigot** doesn't know which one to use. Delete the older one and it would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find main class `me.skyter.hardcore.HardcorePlguin'

I would recommend changing this to where your Main class that extends JavaPlugin is located. I also see a spelling issue, me.skyter.hardcore.Hardcore**Plguin**. That's where your error is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you specifically indicate your Main class (the class with 'extends JavaPlugin') in your plugin.yml file.

It should look something like this:

```
main: com.YouWebsite.PackageName.Main
name: ProjectName
version: 1.0
author: YourName
```

If you don't identify where your Main class is, your plugin won't be able to run properly.

You can identify what the issue is in the error message that says:

```
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `me.skyter.hardcore.HardcorePlguin'
```